# Проблемы асинхронной работы с LRUCashe

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-handler

Я пытаюсь воссоздать работу библиотек типа picasso в самом простом варианте. Для кеширования битмапов я использую LRUCashe. И вот мой первый метод, вызываемый для загрузки указанного в параметрах битмапа в указанную там же вьюху
Recycledet это просто мой контейнер для адреса картинки и scale с нужными размерами

```
public void loadBitmapToImgViewLikePicassa(final ImageView fView,final Recycledet fRecycl)
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    final Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapAsync(fRecycl);
                    if(bitmap!=null)
                        fView.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                fView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            }
                        });
                }
            }).start();
    }
```

Тут очевидно, что в новом треде для взаимодействия с вьюхой нам надо использовать пост для синхронности да. Дальше функция получения битмапа:

```
public Bitmap getBitmapAsync(final Recycledet Image) {

    Log.e(TAG, Image.getIconAdress());
    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromMemCache(Image.getIconAdress());
    if (bitmap == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "cashed bitmap return null");
        bitmap = Image.getIcon();
        if (bitmap != null)
        {
            final Bitmap finalBitmap = bitmap;
            mHandrel.post(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        addBitmapToMemoryCache(Image.getIconAdress(), finalBitmap);
                    }
                });
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
    Log.e(TAG, bitmap.getByteCount()+"bytes");
    return bitmap;
}'
```

Вот тут я в принципе заподозрил, что асинхронная работа с LRUCashe не так проста как кажется, по этому в случае, когда битмам приходится добавлять в кеш, я делаю это через post, отправленный в главный поток.

Вот ещё код самой работы с кешем кстати:

```
private void addBitmapToMemoryCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null) {
        mMemoryCache.put(key, bitmap);

    }
}

private Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(String key) {
    return (Bitmap)mMemoryCache.get(key);
}'
```

Ну в итоге эта конструкция работает очень страшно при каждом новом обращении к первой функции в кеше разрастается хаос. Дебагер показал, что по ходу работы с кешем, в его поле под названием table, которое вроде есть map со значениями ключ-битмап, так вот там беспорядточно разкидываются null между нормальными записями.
И я только что вспомнил, что LRU значит что при каждом запросе к значению, это значение меняет свое положение в кеше. 
Значит ли это, что для исправления моего хаоса надо всю работу с LRUCashe организовывать в одном потоке через свой единый Handler? Или это не важно и вобще пропадет весь смысл разраралеливания данной схемы, а хаос рождается по другой причине?
Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я и предположил, если контролировать все запросы к LRUCashe в рамках одного Thread, ситуация улучшается. Больше не будет никакого бардака в Мапах и все пары значений будут на своих местах.
Что бы гарантировать такую синхронность работы и не сильно потерять в скорости выполнения загрузок, предлагаю разделить всю работу на два постоянных треда и один дополнительно одноразовый. Все пересылки данных между тредами можно удобно организовать в новом объекте, который будет создаваться для каждой новой загрузки.
Однако само создание объектов загрузки лучше инкапчулировать в одном объекте управления кешем, что бы в нем единожды создать дополнительны тред для работы с кешем. Такой обьект у нас уже есть, в нем же происходит инициализация всей структуры LRUCashe:

```
public class GalleryCasheHelper 
{
static final String TAG = "CASHE_HELPER";

private LruCache mMemoryCache;
private DiskLruCache DiskCache;

private static final long DISK_CACHE_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 10; // 10MB
private static final String DISK_CACHE_SUBDIR = "thumbnails";

private Handler mHandrel;

private CasheThread mThread = new CasheThread();

private Context mContext;


public GalleryCasheHelper(Context context)
{
    mContext = context;

    int mSize = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.abc_dropdownitem_icon_width);

    final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory());
    final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

    mHandrel = new Handler();

    File DirCache=new File(context.getCacheDir()+DISK_CACHE_SUBDIR);
    try
    {
        DiskCache = DiskLruCache.open(DirCache, 0, 500, DISK_CACHE_SIZE);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {}

    mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
        @Override
        protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
            return bitmap.getByteCount();
        }
    };
}

public void loadBitmapToView2(ImageView fView, Recycledet fRecycld)
{
    new Loader(fView,fRecycld);
}

private class CasheThread extends Thread
{
    public Handler mThreadHandler = new Handler();
    public boolean isStarted;

    @Override
    public void start()
    {
        super.start();
        mThreadHandler = new Handler();
        isStarted = true;
    }

    public void next()
    {
        /* TODO
        if(mThreadHandler.getLooper().getQueue().isIdle())
            stop();*/
    }
}

private void addBitmapToMemoryCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null) {
        mMemoryCache.put(key, bitmap);

    }
}

private Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(String key) {
    return (Bitmap)mMemoryCache.get(key);
}
}
```

И вот сам объект Loader, заправляющий всем распараллеливанием нашей загрузки:

```
private class Loader
{
    private ImageView mView;
    private Recycledet mRecycledet;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;

    public Loader(ImageView fView, Recycledet fRecycl)
    {
        mView = fView;
        mRecycledet = fRecycl;

        final String key = mRecycledet.getIconAdress();

        if (!mThread.isStarted)
            mThread.start();
        mThread.mThreadHandler.post(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    mBitmap = (Bitmap)mMemoryCache.get(key);
                    if(mBitmap==null)
                        loadBitmapFomRecycle(mRecycledet);
                    else
                        setBitmapToView(mBitmap);
                }
        });
    }

    private void loadBitmapFomRecycle(final Recycledet fRecycldt)
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    final Bitmap fBitmap = fRecycldt.getIcon();
                    addBitmapToCasheAndView(fRecycldt,fBitmap);
                }
            }).start();
    }

    private void addBitmapToCasheAndView(final Recycledet fRecycldt,final Bitmap fBitmap)
    {
        if (fBitmap != null)
        {
            setBitmapToView(fBitmap);
            mThread.mThreadHandler.post(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        addBitmapToMemoryCache(fRecycldt.getIconAdress(), fBitmap);
                        mThread.next();
                    }
            });
        }
        mThread.next();
    }

    private void setBitmapToView(final Bitmap fBitmap)
    {
        if(fBitmap!=null)
            mView.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mView.setImageBitmap(fBitmap);

                    }
                });
        mThread.next();
    }
}
```

Вот. Для доведения структуры до логического конца нужно ещё реализовать метод next(), который останавливает CasheThread на то время, пока никаких запросов к загрузке не поступает. Или не нужно?

Comment: Для большей оптимизации можно добавить очистку старых лоадеров, работающих с одним и тем же вью, если сами вьюхи это элементы RecyclerView. Но это ой сколько работы со всеми нашими потоками